# setTabLabel() not working as expected for subtab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, workspaceapi

We have used setTabLabel() for a subtab that opens on a custom button.
Below is the code in init method for button click action.

```
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
      
           var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
        var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
        var conName = component.get("v.conName");
        workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
            tabId: focusedTabId,
            label: conName
        });
    })
    $A.util.addClass(component.find("refreshButton"), "slds-hide");
    helper.fetchPickListVal(component, 'File_Type__c', 'ftype');
    
},
```

Issue: This works fine only for the first time. If we close the subtab and open it again tab label shows 'Loading' instead of conName. We need to refresh the whole page again in order to bring back the conName. Please let me know what could be the issue here.

Comment: Reason might be that the component which is having this `doInit` logic is not executing multiple times.

Comment: I am closing the subtab and opening it again by clicking on the same custom button. Doesn't seem like the doInit does not fire.